# ASP.NET MVC 6 Connection Sting config.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

The issue that I am having is when I run the program I get a "System.NullReferenceException" exception. Not sure what the problem is. This issue also doesn't allow me to start a data migration using dnx.

[image]

[image]

```
#config.json

 {
  "Data": {
  "DefaultConnection": {
  "Connectionstring": "Data Server=.\\ERKANDEMIR5E91;Initial Catalog=RegistrationDB;Integrated Security=True;"
      }
   }
}
```

## scoolDbContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata;
using School.Models;

namespace School.Context
{
    public class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
    {
       public DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
    }
}
```

## Statup.cs

```
namespace School
{
public class Startup
{
    public static Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup (IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //setup configuration sources
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .AddJsonFile("config.json")
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();

    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //add services to container
        services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<SchoolDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
        services.AddMvc();

        //resolve dependency injections
        services.AddScoped<IRegistrationRepo, RegistrationRepo>();
        services.AddScoped<SchoolDbContext, SchoolDbContext>();           
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseWelcomePage();

    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
   }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add more full code of `Statup.cs` (using for example). Could you remove `services.AddScoped<SchoolDbContext, SchoolDbContext>();`? I personally would prefer to remove `OnConfiguring` from `SchoolDbContext` and to use `.AddDbContext<SchoolDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));`. You can try to rename `config.json` to `appsettings.json` which is the standard name for the app-config now.

Comment: try to rename `Data Source=.\\ERKANDEMIR5E91` to `Server=.\\ERKANDEMIR5E91;` in `config.json`. The syntax will mean that you use SQL srever on the current computer and `ERKANDEMIR5E91` is the name of the instance of SQL Server. Is it what you do?

Comment: Hey @Oleg I'm still getting the same error. FYI, `ERKANDEMIR5E91 ` is the name of the SQL Server

Comment: Hey @Oleg Please see updated summary. I have updated the code as you recommended. I am not getting the `System.NullReferenceException` error anymore. However I am still not able to initialize a data migration. I have attached the screen shot of the error

Comment: You should **remove the line** `services.AddScoped<SchoolDbContext, SchoolDbContext>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the code

```cs
public Startup (IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //setup configuration sources
    Configuration = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
```

to

```cs
public Startup (IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //setup configuration sources
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

or to

```cs
public Startup (IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //setup configuration sources
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, once I removed `services.AddScoped<SchoolDbContext, SchoolDbContext>();` and changed `Server=.\\ERKANDEMIR5E91;` to `Source=ERKANDEMIR5E91;` it worked

Comment: @ErkanDemir: You are welcome! I just posted you the comment with the same information :-)